# ASP.NET MVC5 - Image upload to SQL Server 2008R2 Standard

Tags: asp.net-mvc, sql-server-2008-r2, image-uploading, asp.net-mvc-5

I am semi-new to ASP.NET MVC, I have used it in the past but not to the extent of what I have been planning to use it for and to learn from for some projects I am working on.  I know this question has been asked a lot over the internet and there are many solutions so I will try and keep this as specific as possible regarding uploading images and storing them in a SQL Server database.

I am currently using .NET 4.5 with MVC5 (VS 2013) to do all my coding.

To begin I found a great tutorial that got me up and running with being able to upload images to my SQL Server 2008 database: http://www.mikesdotnetting.com/Article/125/ASP.NET-MVC-Uploading-and-Downloading-Files

Everything works great after I figured out how the functions worked from the site, but the issue I am having is that I have multiple text fields that I want to include data from into the SQL Server database along with including an image upload feature that I created based off the tutorial I found online.

The first part of my code is the Models (BeerList.cs)

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Data.Entity;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;

namespace YBPP_Production.Models
{
public class BeerList
{
    public int ID { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Name is required")]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Company is required.")]
    public string Company { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Type is required.")]
    public string Type { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "City is required.")]
    public string City { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "State is required.")]
    public string State { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Country is required")]
    public string Country { get; set; }

    public string ABV { get; set; }
    public string IBU { get; set; }
}

public class Info : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<DBName> MoreDB { get; set; }
}
}
```

The string listed there are the text fields I am trying to pull into my database and I can do that but when I try to mix in the image upload feature either the text will upload or the image will upload depending on how I do the calls.

The Controllers section of my code (BeerListController.cs)

```
   // GET: /BeerList/Create
    public ActionResult Create()
    {
        return View();
    }

    // POST: /BeerList/Create
    // To protect from overposting attacks, please enable the specific properties you want to bind to, for 
    // more details see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=317598.
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult Create([Bind(Include = "ID,Name,Company,Type,City,State,Country,ABV,IBU")] BeerList beerlist)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            db.BeerListDB.Add(beerlist);
            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }

        return View(beerlist);
    }

    public ActionResult FileUpload(HttpPostedFileBase file)
    {
        //Begin the Image Uploading Process
        foreach (string upload in Request.Files)
        {
            if (!Request.Files[upload].HasFile()) continue;

            string mimeType = Request.Files[upload].ContentType;
            Stream fileStream = Request.Files[upload].InputStream;
            string fileName = Path.GetFileName(Request.Files[upload].FileName);
            int fileLength = Request.Files[upload].ContentLength;
            byte[] fileData = new byte[fileLength];
            fileStream.Read(fileData, 0, fileLength);

            const string connect = @"Server=localhost;database=<database-name>;uid=<username-here>;pwd=<there-a-passwordhere>";
            using (var conn = new SqlConnection(connect))
            {
                var qry = "INSERT INTO BeerLists (FileContent, mimeType, FileName) VALUES (@FileContent, @mimeType, @FileName)";
                var cmd = new SqlCommand(qry, conn);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FileContent", fileData);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@MimeType", mimeType);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FileName", fileName);
                conn.Open();
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }
        }
        return View();
    }
```

The view part of my code (Create.cshtml)

```
@model YBPP_Production.Models.BeerList

@{
ViewBag.Title = "Create";
}

<h2>Create</h2>


@using (Html.BeginForm(null, null, FormMethod.Post, new { enctype="multipart/form-data" }))
{
@Html.AntiForgeryToken()

<div class="form-horizontal">
    <h4>BeerList</h4>
    <hr />
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Name, new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Name)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Name)
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Company, new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Company)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Company)
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Type, new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Type)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Type)
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.City, new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.City)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.City)
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.State, new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.State)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.State)
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Country, new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Country)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Country)
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.ABV, new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.ABV)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.ABV)
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.IBU, new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.IBU)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.IBU)
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <p class="control-label col-md-2">Image Upload:</p>
        <div class="col-md-10">
        <input type="file" id="ImageUpload" name="ImageUpload" />
         </div>
    </div>
        <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
            <input type="submit" name="Submit" id="Submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-default" />
        </div>
    </div>
    </div>
}

<div>
    @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")
</div>

@section Scripts {
   @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
}
```

So what I am looking to hopefully get help with is being able to merge the function of Create and `FileUpload` into one function so that the form will take both the text in the text-fields and the image that gets uploaded with it. I have read a bunch of other people's posts and code and they all seem to have their own way to doing things but everyone example never includes text-fields or any other form functions just the basic image upload.

Thank you very very much in advance for any direction/suggestions/help to this issue.

Comment: Did you manage to get this working? This is exactly what I am trying to do at the moment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create model that contains HttpPostedFileBase, then save your entire form with selected file.

Model:

```
public class BeerListModel
{
    public int ID { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Name is required")]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public HttpPostedFileBase file { get; set; }

}
```

View:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm(null, null, FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
{
@Html.AntiForgeryToken()
<div class="form-horizontal">
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Name)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Name)
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <p class="control-label col-md-2">Image Upload:</p>
        <input type="file" id="file" name="file" />
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <input type="submit" name="Submit" id="Submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-default" />
    </div>
</div>
```

}

Controller:

```
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult Create(BeerListModel model)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            //your logic 
        }

        return View("Create");
    }
```

Comment: Thank you for the information; I am still a bit confused as to what I should put as far as my logic for the Controller.  I know the general idea is going to be something with reading the bytes of the file (image) that will be uploaded and then I figure I will need to use the database submitting function in my original create.  Would it be possible to explain a bit further details what logic I might be looking for in the controller.  Thank you again.

Answer (score 0):

@Szakus' answer is the overall direction you want to go with respect to uploading a file, however when you asked,  " I am still a bit confused as to what I should put as far as my logic for the Controller" you inadvertently got to the root of your problem.

I would strongly recommend you do some research into [separation of concerns](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separation_of_concerns).  Putting raw SQL code in your controller is not a great idea and will open your application to a host of the other issues.

I know this doesn't really *answer* your question but having been where you are now I can tell you that the old adage, "an ounce of prevention is worth a pound of cure" will save you major headaches down the road.

If you want to see an example of a really good .net MVC project that you can use as sort of a template in building your skills I would recommend the open source shopping cart [nopCommerce](http://nopcommerce.com).